# How to receive php array post parameters in asp?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have a form that I send a select attribute `name="submitted[new_fieldset][c01_mes]"` by POST in PHP and need to receive this using ASP request.form.

PHP Code:

```
<select id="field-c01-mes" name="submitted[new_fieldset][c01_mes]">

    <option value="1" selected="selected">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="3">Março</option>
    <option value="4">Abril</option>

</select>
```

How to receive this array `submitted[new_fieldset][c01_mes]` in ASP `request.form`?

I try it, but:

```
c01_mes = request.form("['submitted']['new_fieldset']['c01_ano']")
```

Comment: post is not php or asp its part of the http protocol

Comment: Why the single quotes in `request.form("['submitted']['new_fieldset']['c01_ano']") ` when they're not in the `name` attribute of your form select element?

Answer (score 1):

Step One (and how you solve this kind of problem) is to see what you have in the Request:

```
For Each sItem In Request.Form
    Response.Write(sItem)
Next
```

This will show you all of the keys... and you can then see what the exact key is. It should (probably) be...

```
Request.Form("submitted[new_fieldset][c01_mes]")
```